# miniconda: install and pin packages using anaconda versions

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm using miniconda to create environments for myself and in order to ensure stability I've currently pinning all my packages.  However, this makes things pretty intensive if I want to bring everything up to date as I need to go through all the packages one by one.

Because of that what I think I'd really like to do is to pin a version of anaconda and use only the packages I want from within that.  Basically use anaconda as a meta-package of pinned versions.

Is there a good way to do this or something similar that allows me to maintain consistent versions across installations and a small environment size without having to pin individual packages?